# What does exponential tilting actually do?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I met the definition of exponential tilting when reading about Cramer's theorem, and am struggling about this definition:

for every $\theta\in\mathbb R$, we define a random variable $X_1^\theta$ with law given by $$\mathbb E[f(X_1^\theta)]:=\mathbb E[f(X_1)\frac{e^{\theta X_1}}{M(\theta)}]$$ for $f\geq 0$ measurable.

What does this exponential tilting actually do? How does the new random variable look like?

I tried to come up with a simple example:

Example. $\theta=2$ and $f(x)=x$. Then $\mathbb E[X\frac{e^{2X}}{M(2)}]=\mathbb E[X\frac{e^{2X}}{\mathbb E[e^{2X}]}]=\frac{\mathbb E[Xe^{2X}]}{\mathbb E[e^{2X}]}$. So the expectation of the new random variable is equal to $\frac{\mathbb E[Xe^{2X}]}{\mathbb E[e^{2X}]}$.

But I still don't have the feeling of it. Could someone give a basic description and give intuition on how it makes Cramer's theorem works by tilting?